# cytpes definition for Handle

Tags: python, ctypes

I am working with a library written in C that has a function which returns a handle (to an object I expect). I have tried a number of different ctypes for this handle, but each time I try to use the handle in the next function I get a Seg Fault. What is the correct way to define (and use) a handle (I have seen examples for Windows, but I'm developing for Linux and MacOS)?

Example Python Code:

```
Provided_Lib = "../libProvided.so"
libc = CDLL(Provided_Lib)

DSHandle = libc.DevInitialze(config1, config2, err_no)
# The line above is modified from the actual to simplify, it does work correctly
#     - if I modify an input it provides he correct error codes.

#This line causes the Seg Dump:
return_code = libc.DevReset(DSHandle)
```

C-Code definitions:

```
INT DevReset(HANDLE hDSer);

#ifndef HANDLE
#define HANDLE  VOID*
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare appropriate `.argtypes` and `.restype`.  Without them, `ctypes` assumes all parameters are `c_int` or pointers and the return type is `c_int` (32-bit).  Since pointers are typically 64-bit on modern OSes the 64-bit handle gets truncated to 32 bits without a proper `.restype`.  For example:

```py
from ctypes import *

Provided_Lib = "../libProvided.so"
libc = CDLL(Provided_Lib)
libc.DevInitialize.argtypes = # put tuple of argument types here...not provided
libc.DevInitialize.restype = c_void_p  # appropriate for a C void*
libc.DevReset.argtypes = c_void_p
libc.DevReset.restype = c_int # or whatever...not provided.
DSHandle = libc.DevInitialize(config1, config2, err_no)
return_code = libc.DevReset(DSHandle)
```

Comment: Thanks- that did it. 
I think the main problem was the return value for DevInitialize wasn't being set correctly to c_void_p